# wso2 Identity Provider Federated Authenticators Missing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, google-authentication, wso2-identity-server

I'm new to wso2 and testing out their API Manager and Identity Server.

I was looking to test creating an IP, authenticating to Google, but when I go to setup the IP, the Federated Authenticators dropdown section is empty, with the exception of "SAML2 Web SSO Configuration".  I was expecting OpenID, OAuth/OpenID, WS-Federation, etc.

Is there something I'm missing with my configuration/installation?

Here is a snippet from the wso2Carbon error log.

```html
TID: [-1] [] [2016-07-12 08:26:59,643]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionCleanUpService} -  Session Data cleanup task is running successfully for removing expired Data {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionCleanUpService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-07-12 09:34:47,410]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-07-12 09:34:47,410-0400] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-07-12 09:34:48,103] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher}
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_jsp._jspService(idp_002dmgt_002dedit_jsp.java:345)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
 at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
 at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
 at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-07-12 09:34:48,138] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher}
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_jsp._jspService(idp_002dmgt_002dedit_jsp.java:345)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:98)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
 at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
 at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
 at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far? This will allow us to identify what might be going wrong

Comment: Hi Matthew.  I'm not a developer and am working from a local Windows installation.  Can you let me know what code to send?  Would this be the XML file under repository\conf\identity\identity-providers?  Thanks again!

Comment: I don't use wso2 but if that XML file is your configuration then posting that (sanitizing sensitive info) would help those who do debug this.

Comment: There are a few default xml files to choose from, but considering this is straight out of the box and directly from wso2 with no customization, I was hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of Identity Server and APIM are you trying out?

Comment: Did you notice any error log in <IS_HOME>repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file?

Comment: APIM v 1.10.0 and IS v 5.1.0. As for error log, I'll reply to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In APIM you will have only option ""SAML2 Web SSO Configuration" to configure federated aunthenticator. You will have to configure wso2 IS as federated authenticator for APIM and in wso2 IS you can configure google as federated aunthenticator.Please follow this blog post[1]

1.http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-access-tokens-for-wso2-api.html

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  This was the missing piece I was looking for!